# HTML5 and Amazon S3 Multi-Part uploads

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, fileapi, html5-filesystem

Is it possible to use the HTML 5 File API (for example, this library: https://github.com/23/resumable.js ) in conjunction with the S3 multi-part upload feature?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but you will need some kind of server backend to handle the Amazon API keys in a more secure way if you are going to make it part of a public website.

You can find what looks like a complete example implementation of this these projects:

- [s3-multipart-upload-browser](https://github.com/ienzam/s3-multipart-upload-browser) which uses a PHP backend
- [s3_multipart](https://github.com/maxgillett/s3_multipart) which uses Ruby.

Please note that I have not used, tested or reviewed these projects.

A rough description of the sequence is as follows:

1. User

   - loads webpage
   - selects file to upload
   - hits upload button
2. Webpage

   - sends info about file to server
3. Server

   - creates multipart upload with Amazon API
   - sends "key"(filename) and "upload id" back to Webpage
4. Webpage

   - works out size of parts
   - requests Server to sign part passing "key", "upload id", part info
5. Server

   - signs a part request, sends "part upload url", "date" and "auth header"
6. Webpage

   - sends part data directly to Amazon S3 via "part upload url" using "date" and "auth header"
   - keeps track of part ids
7. Server & Webpage

   - repeats 5 & 6 for each additional part, resuming if required
8. Webpage

   - makes "upload complete" request to server (passing all the part info)
9. Server

   - makes request to Amazon API to complete the creation of file
10. Webpage

    - inform user of error or success

Notes:

- If upload is aborted, this must also be handled server side else the parts / uploads started will be left to take up space in the S3 Bucket.
- It might take a few minutes to complete the "upload complete" request to Amazon.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I've actually started implementing the protocol you detailed before, but haven't gotten around to actually finishing it yet: https://github.com/keichan34/s3uploader/tree/2.0-wip

Comment: Great, I've noticed you are using Ruby in your project and also found another Ruby project which I have added to the answer for your reference.

Comment: Here is another example in PHP [https://github.com/ienzam/s3-multipart-upload-browser](https://github.com/ienzam/s3-multipart-upload-browser)

Comment: @BausTheBig this is/was the first project linked in the answer. Obviously it wasn't clear so thanks to your comment I have updated the answer to make the link more clear.

Comment: Great thanks! The answer is very detailed, exactly what I needed right now. This is another interesting project (it uses Python) to look at: https://github.com/cinely/mule-uploader#mule-upload

Comment: @BausTheBig actually, the bulk of the project is written in Javascript, it only needs a small server-side endpoint, which can be written in any language easily. The "canonical" endpoint is written in Python though (Flask).